# Open set in the sup-metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

can you please explain why is the following so? Or at least point me in a direction which can help me find the answer?

Given a set G of functions g: $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that |g(x)| < 1 for all x, is not an open set in the sup-metric space.

The book recommends using the function $g(x) = (2/\pi)tan^{-1}(x) $ since this would mean that we will not be able to find any positive $\epsilon$ contained in the open ball $B_{\epsilon }(g)\subseteq  G$

But wouldn't this be false if we take any nonzero x contained within (-1,1)? Say for e.g. x = 0.5?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re not really interested in what happens at a single value of $x$. The point is that for any $\epsilon>0$ the open ball $B_\epsilon(g)$ is not a subset of $G$. I’ll explain in a moment why this is so, but first let’s see why it shows that $G$ is not open. On the one hand it’s clear that $g\in G$, since $$\left|\frac2{\pi}\tan^{-1}x\right|<1$$

for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Thus, if $G$ were open there would have to be some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(g)\subseteq G$: that’s what it means for $G$ to be open in this topology. If we can show that no such $\epsilon$ exists, then we’ve shown that $G$ is not open.

Now let $\epsilon>0$. We know that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac2{\pi}\tan^{-1}x=1\;,$$

so there is an $x_0\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$|1-g(x)|=\left|1-\frac2{\pi}\tan^{-1}x\right|<\frac{\epsilon}2\tag{1}$$

whenever $x\ge x_0$. In fact, since $g(x)<1$ for all $x$, $(1)$ says that

$$1-\frac{\epsilon}2<g(x)<1$$

for all $x\ge x_0$.

Now let $f(x)=g(x)+\frac{\epsilon}2$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Then $d(f,g)=\frac{\epsilon}2$, so $f\in B_\epsilon(g)$. However, for each $x\ge x_0$ we have

$$f(x)=g(x)+\frac{\epsilon}2>\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}2\right)+\frac{\epsilon}2=1\;,$$

so $f\notin G$. Thus, $f\in B_\epsilon(g)\setminus G$, and it follows that $B_\epsilon(g)\nsubseteq G$. Finally, $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, so *no* open ball centred at $g$ is a subset of $G$, and $G$ is not open.

Comment: @Sanjou: You’re welcome.